# finishing a TeXStudio autocompleted command argument efficiently

Tags: texstudio

Suppose that TeXStudio has autocompleted a LaTeX command that requires one argument, such as `\widehat`.  It inserts a pair of matching braces for that argument.  When I have filled in the argument by typing, I have to move the insertion caret past the right brace somehow, to proceed with the rest of my document.  I can do that by typing the "right-arrow" key.  But that key is a big jump away from the touch-typing portion of the keyboard.  I could also point andclick with the mouse -- but that's even further away.

Is there some way that I can complete the current argument using keys in the standard, touch-typing area?

In case it matters, I am using TeXStudio 2.10.4 under Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply type the closing brace and TeXstudio will move behind it.